# Bootstrap 5 Collapse cannot collapse after open it (working with vue3)

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I am working on a project using Vue 3 and Bootstrap 5. I encountered an issue with Bootstrap collapse. While I am able to successfully open the collapse, I am unable to collapse it again.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ivanv/vue-collapse-transition": "^1.0.2",
    "all": "^0.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.5",
    "bp-vuejs-dropdown": "^2.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "datatables.net-bs5": "^1.13.6",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "js-base64": "^3.7.2",
    "lz-string": "^1.5.0",
    "npm": "^9.8.1",
    "vee-validate": "^4.7.4",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-ctk-date-time-picker": "^3.0.0-alpha.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vue2-daterange-picker": "^0.6.8",
    "vue3-chart-v2": "^0.8.3",
    "vuejs-datetimepicker": "^1.1.13",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0",
    "xlsx": "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.19.3/xlsx-0.19.3.tgz"
  },
```

main.js

```
import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount("#app");
```

myscript.js

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="bg-white">
      <div class="row gap-3">
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"> Link with href </a>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Button with data-bs-target
          </button>
        </p>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
          <div class="card card-body">Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I think the issue is related to package conflicts, but I have tried various methods and have not been able to identify the problem.

Comment: I've set the breakpoint at bootstrap.js source code. After Doing the hide() function, the element will collapse. But once it jump out the hide() function, element's classList add 'show' class by nobody.

Comment: you're missing `@popperjs/core` which is a dependency of bootstrap.  run `npm i @popperjs/core`. I have no problem with your code in a [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-jkpcsi?file=src%2FApp.vue) with all required dependencies installed.

Comment: I installed @popperjs/core, but I still encounter issues. I've identified that the problem arises from Bootstrap; when toggling, the class changes to "collapsing" immediately. Consequently, when checking isShown(), it evaluates to false, leading to the execution of show().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've identified the issue. The problem lies in my partner rewriting `import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'`. causing conflicts with the Bootstrap execution later on.